# How to download tgz file from a url and decompress it efficiently?

Tags: c#

I have a `.tgz` file that I need to download given a url inside a `Testing` folder and then decompress it. I am able to download the `.tgz` file successfully from the url and also able to successfully decompress it without any issues. My `.tgz` file will be approx `100 MB` max. I am using `SharpZipLib` library here to decompress.

There are two parts to this:

- Download `.tgz` file from a url in a particular folder.
- If file is downloaded successfully then only decompress `.tgz` file in that same folder othewise not.

Below is my code:

```
private void DownloadTGZFile(string url, string fileToDownload)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(url + fileToDownload, "Testing/configs.tgz");
    }
    Stream inStream = File.OpenRead("Testing/configs.tgz");
    Stream gzipStream = new GZipInputStream(inStream);

    TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(gzipStream);
    tarArchive.ExtractContents("Testing/");
    tarArchive.Close();

    gzipStream.Close();
    inStream.Close();
}
```

**Question:**

I wanted to check on below things:

- Is using `WebClient` efficient here? If not, then what can I use to download the file efficiently for me considering file size is 100 MB max?
- Also can I add a timeout here so that if I am not able to download the file in that time period, then it just times out. But it should retry for 3 times (or with some retry policy) and skip it if not able to by logging an error for the last try.
- And if it is able to download the .tgz file successfully then decompress it in the same folder.

I am a newbie who started working with C# so still confuse on usage of `WebClient` and not sure if it is the right way to do it also. And this will be a production code so wanted to see what's the best way to re-write this whole code if there is any.

Comment: Have you considered to use `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`? (Or `RestSharp` or `Flurl`)

Comment: I am ok using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`. Can you provide an example on how my code should be with that and also any improvements considering it's a production code? @PeterCsala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DownloadTGZFile` does two things, which is one thing too many.

- It does what it name says it does (download a .TGZ file),
- but it also unpacks the TGZ file, and that is not in the method's name.

Unpacking the file should be a different method. You should then have a new method that calls both methods.

---

Also, please follow [the Microsoft guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions):

> The PascalCasing convention, used for all identifiers except parameter
> names, **capitalizes the first character of each word (including
> acronyms over two letters in length)**, as shown in the following
> examples:
>
> `PropertyDescriptor HtmlTag`
>
> A special case is made for two-letter acronyms in which both letters
> are capitalized, as shown in the following identifier:
>
> `IOStream`

Thus the method name should be `DownloadTgzFile`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you provide an example on how my code should look like considering it is a production code. It will help me understand better also.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally not write the archive to disk unless it's extremely huge (we're talking gigabytes here, and not "it might be gigabytes", but **is** gigabytes).

Open a stream to the download response content and pass it to your gzip/tar decompressor streams, and then extract the files as they come.

And of course, use better names, that function should be called `ExtractTgzFile` and take an `Uri` parameter to download (if you use the modern CodeAnalysis package, you'll get a warning for this specifically).

And after that's done, you should rewrite it as an `async` function, because right now you're wasting time on your caller thread waiting for a file to download, which is unacceptable.

Comment: My archive file will be 100 MB max. Do you think you can provide an example on how to do this right way? It will help me understand better as I am pretty new in C#.

Comment: You just `await` a `HttpClient.GetAsync` call, then call the `Content` property to get the `HttpContent` instance, then `await` `ReadAsStreamAsync` on it to get the stream. Once you have your stream, the rest of the code is the same as what you wrote, pass it to your gzip & tgz stream readers and extract.

Comment: Do you think you can provide an example on how to do this? I am still confuse on how to use HttpClient here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's confusing? What did you write and what doesn't work?